# If someone knows my Gmail ID and password is it possible to view my YouTube browsing history data from their own PC or mobile?

Tags: networking

If someone knows my Gmail ID and password is it possible to view my YouTube browsing history data from their own PC or mobile ? If my sync is off in my mobile.

Comment: By default, YouTube saves your watch history to your account. You can see this history from any browser or app as long as you're logged in to the account.

Comment: Before additional people answer this question, the author has an [existing question](http://superuser.com/questions/1151318/can-someone-see-my-browsing-history-from-their-pc-or-mobile-if-they-know-my-emai), this is basically just a duplicate of that question.  This question is still not on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes **if** you're logged into google/youtube on the device you're viewing youtube on then the history is added to your google account.

You can view this history (and amend it) here: [myactivity.google.com](https://myactivity.google.com/)

This will be viewable on any device logged into the same account (in youtube history and google history), or if someone signs into this account on any device.